# hp envy wifi switch not shown on rfkill

Tags: wireless, hp, ralink

I have an HP envy 15 inch, newly installed with U16 it has RT3290 wifi chip.

My laptop has an wifi switch that I haven't been able to turn on. It always shows an orange light which indicates the wifi is off. I suspect this is what is causing me a whole host of wifi related issues.

I ran rfkill but it listed nothing. So how can I make the physical wifi switch work?

Edit for more info as per request:

```
root@HP-ENVY# rfkill list all
root@HP-ENVY# lsmod | grep -e wmi -e lap
hp_wmi                 16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd                    81920  17 snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
wmi                    20480  1 hp_wmi
root@HP-ENVY#
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the results of these terminal commands: `rfkill list all` and also: `lsmod | grep -e wmi -e lap`

Comment: @chili555 updated info as per request